# Algorithm to simplify a weighted directed graph of debts

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I've been using a little python script I wrote to manage debt amongst my roommates. It works, but there are some missing features, one of which is simplifying unnecessarily complicated debt structures. For example, if the following weighted directed graph represents some people and the arrows represent debts between them (Alice owes Bob $20 and Charlie $5, Bob owes Charlie $10, etc.):

[image: graph1]

It is clear that this graph should be simplified to the following graph:

[image: graph1-simplified]

There's no sense in $10 making its way from Alice to Bob and then from Bob to Charlie if Alice could just give it to Charlie directly.

The goal, then, in the general case is to take a debt graph and simplify it (i.e. produce a new graph with the same nodes but different edges) such that

1. No node has edges pointing both in and out of it (no useless money changing hands)
2. All nodes have the same "flow" through them as they did in the original graph (it is identical in terms of where the money ends up).

By "flow", I mean the value of all inputs minus all outputs (is there a technical term for this? I am no graph theory expert). So in the example above, the flow values for each node are:

- Bob: +10
- Alice: -25
- Charlie: +15

You can see that the first and second graphs have the same flow through each node, so this is a good solution. There are some other easy cases, for example, any cycle can be simplified by removing the lowest valued edge and subtracting its value from all other edges.

This:

[image: graph2]

should be simplified into this:

[image: graph2-simplified]

I can't imagine that no one has studied this problem; I just don't know what terms to search for to find info on it (again, not a graph theory expert). I've been looking for several hours to no avail, so my question is this: what is an algorithm that will produce a simplification (new graph) according to the conditions specified above for any weighted directed graph?

Comment: What is the criteria for finishing.  Even in your last case, Daniel can give Bob '3' and Alice gives Charlie '8' and Bob '7'.

Comment: Ooh, good point. I think that the optimal algorithm would also minimize the number of edges (what you suggest), but I would settle for one that meets the two criteria I specify in the question.

Comment: This problem is interesting from an algorithmic point of view, but do you think this works in practice? If A owes B and B owes C, why should C get the money from A? C didn't know that A was broke when lending money to B...

Comment: We use this to manage debts incurred by, for example, buying communal food and paying bills, there's no direct lending per se. The idea of having A pay C directly is to avoid needless logistics (A has to track down B to give money, B then has to track down C, as opposed to A tracking down C directly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Simple algorithm

You can find in O(n) how much money who is expecting to get or pay. So you could simply create two lists, one for debit and the other for credit, and then balance the head of the two lists until they are empty. From your first example:

- Initial state: Debit: (A: 25), Credit: (B: 15, C: 10)
- First transaction, A:15 -> B: Debit: (A: 10), Credit: (C: 10)
- Second transaction, A:10 -> C: Debit: (), Credit: ()

The transactions define the edges of your graph. For n persons involved, there will be at most n-1 transactions=edges. In the beginning, the total length of both lists is n. In each step, at least one of the lists (debit/credit) gets shorter by one, and in the last both lists disappear at once.

The issue is that, in general, this graph doesn't have to be similar to the original graph, which, as I get your intention, is a requirement. (Is it? There are cases where the optimal solution consists of adding new edges. Imagine A owing B and B owing C the same amount of money, A should pay C directly but this edge is not in the graph of debts.)

### Less transactions

If the goal is just to construct an equivalent graph, you could search the creditor and debitor lists (as in the section above) for exact matches, or for cases where the sum of credit matches the debit of *one* person (or the other way round). Look for [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing). For other cases you will have no other choice than splitting the flows, but even the simple algorithm above produces a graph which has one fewer edge than there are persons involved -- at most.

**EDIT**: Thanks to j_random_hacker for pointing out that a solution with less than n-1 edges is possible iff there is a group of persons whose total debts matches the credit of another group of persons: Then, the problem can be split into two subproblems with a total cost of n-2 edges for the transaction graph. Unfortunately, the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is NP-hard.

### A flow problem?

Perhaps this also can be transformed to a [min-cost flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).
If you want just to simplify your original graph, you construct a flow on it, the edge capacities are the original amounts of debit/credit. The debitors serve as inflow nodes (through a connector node which serves all debitors with edges of capacity that equals their total debt), the creditors are used as outflow nodes (with a similar connector node).

If you want to minimize the number of transactions, you will prefer keeping the "big" transactions and reducing the "small" ones. Hence, the cost of each edge could be modeled as the inverse of the flow on that edge.

Comment: I don't think this fits exactly.  He has cycles and other complications.  According to your link it is only directed graphs.  Ie, there are produces/source and consumer/sinks.  In this case, we have cycles.  However, you can transform the problem by finding the minimum value in a cycle and then subtracting it from all nodes.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Flow algorithms can cope with cycles, just the way you suggested.

Comment: Hmmm I like your first approach; I don't care how similar the final graph is to the initial so long as it meets my criteria above, adding new edges is fine and desirable (as in your example). I'll play around with this. I'm not sure where I would go with the min-cost analysis, as I need to transform the network into a new one, not just analyze a single network.

Comment: I don't understand how what you proposed in the first paragaph can be achieved in O(n); you'll need to look at all edges, so that's O(n+m), no?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done in O(n) where n is the number of edges. Just iterate over the edges adding and subtracting from the node flow values (which is a constant time operation) as you go.

Comment: @G.Bach: Right, you need to look at all edges. Let's just think of n as "problem size"...

Comment: It's not obvious to me that sorting debits and credits by absolute value will tend to minimise the number of transactions.  Won't ordering debits arbitrarily, and credits arbitrarily, then matching them off as before create about the same number of transactions?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You're right, removed the misleading reference to sorting.

Answer (score 23):

Here is an academic paper which investigates this problem in great detail. There is also some sample code for the different algorithms in Section 8 towards the end.

#### [Verhoeff, T. (2004). Settling multiple debts efficiently : an invitation to computing science. Informatics in Education, 3(1), 105-126.](https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/settling-multiple-debts-efficiently-an-invitation-to-computing-sc)

Comment: How did you find this paper? There's no way I would've found it on my own - it is exactly on topic and delivers a comprehensive analysis of problem. Thanks!

Comment: link is broken, please upload alternative link

Comment: a google search for the title and author gave me this link https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/settling-multiple-debts-efficiently-an-invitation-to-computing-sc that is working right now

Answer (score 4):

I've actually encountered this problem in exactly the same situation as you :)

I think krlmlr's various solution don't quite solve the problem exactly.  I'll have a think about how to solve it exactly (in the minimum-edges sense), but in the meantime, a practical alternative solution to your problem is to invent a new person, **Steve**:

1. Steve is not actually a person.  Steve is just a bucket, with a piece of paper attached to it.
2. Everyone calculates the net amount that they owe (or are owed, if negative), and writes it on the piece of paper, alongside their name.
3. Anyone whose net position is that they owe money gives that net amount of money to Steve when they can, and crosses off their name.
4. Everyone whose net position is that they are owed money takes that money from Steve when they see Steve has it, and crosses off their name.

If a person who owes money can't pay all of it at once, they can just give Steve what they can currently afford, and take this amount off the total-owing figure against their name.  Likewise if you are owed more money than Steve currently has on hand, you can take all of the money he currently has, and take that amount off the total-owed against your name.

If everyone agrees at the start to pay Steve only the full amount, then every net-ower makes exactly one deposit, and every net-owed person make exactly one withdrawal (although this may require multiple checks on Steve to see whether he currently has sufficient cash on hand).  The good thing about Steve is that he's always around, and is never too busy to sort out finances.  Unfortunately he's very gullible, so Alice, Bob and Charlie need to already trust one another not to take advantage of him.

Comment: My "simple" solution produces a graph with at most n-1 edges (=transactions) for n persons involved. Always. IMHO, a better solution is possible only under the conditions shown in the "less transactions" section. If Steve is involved, as in your solution, the transaction graph will contain n edges.

Comment: @krlmlr: True, but I'm proposing this only as an easy practical solution, not an optimal solution.  Better solutions (than n-1 edges) are actually possible whenever there is a subset of debtors whose debts sum to x and a subset of creditors whose credits sum to x -- it's not necessary for there to be just a single debtor in the group, or just a single creditor.  The reason is that this group of (say, k) debtors and creditors forms a subproblem that can itself be solved with at most k-1 edges, leaving n-k people whose problem can be solved with at most n-k-1 edges, for at most n-2 overall.

Comment: Interesting thought. But then it's the NP-hard [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)...

Comment: Haha I like this, a hardware solution to the problem :)
I've implemented krlmlr's simple solution because its good enough for my purposes, but this is cool also

Comment: "Steve is just a bucket" This can literally be done by putting a bucket (hardware) in your kitchen and skipping the software part entirely.

Comment: I'm trying to consolidate debts after a trip with a group of friends and this is the most practical real world solution IMO. Everyone with a negative balance pays the trip lead and the trip lead pays members with a positive balance. The trip lead is the bucket here.

Answer (score 1):

Taking hints from the algorithm suggested by @krlmlr I have written this code with a sample example which consists of 2 heaps, one for debit and the other for credit and it iteratively balances the maximum values from both the heaps. Code might look confusing because python only has min_heap and I needed to create a max_heap for the people that need to receive the value (credit heap), so I multiplied the values by -1.

https://github.com/Shivashish1010/Simplify-Debts/blob/master/simplify_debts.py

Comment: copied the code and worked like a charm.