# Debt optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization

What algorithm you may propose to solve next task?
Or what other known optimization task is similar to it?

You have N people (N > 2). Some people owe money to another people. You need to optimize money flow between them.

Example:

- P1 owes P2 30 USD
- P1 owes P3 10 USD
- P2 owes P3 20 USD

And optimization would be:

- P1 owes P2 10 USD
- P1 owes P3 30 USD

Comment: There are two different optimizations possible here: less debts, or smaller total debts. Your example does both (3->2 and 60->40).

Comment: I believe minimizing the total outstanding debt value subject to no change in net positions can be formulated as an LP (linear programming problem). Minimizing the number of debts will require some binary variables (so no longer a strict LP but a MIP- a Mixed Integer Programming problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a nice solution.

1. Compute final status for each person (aka node in graph). You do this by summing all income values to this person/node and subtracting all outcomes. In my example:

   *Statuses:*

   - P1: -40 USD
   - P2: 10 USD
   - P3: 30 USD
2. Match the smallest number (would always be negative) with the biggest number (would always be positive), and update list of final statues. In example:

   *Matched:*

   - P1 owes P3: 30 USD.

   *Statuses:*

   - P1: -10 USD
   - P2: 10 USD
3. Repeat 2 until all matched (status list is empty).

   *Matched:*

   - P1 owes P3: 30 USD
   - P1 owes P2: 10 USD

Answer (score -1):

if you are still looking for the solution here is the answer from other StackOverflow question and it goes very in-depth in all of the possibilities of solution. Link: [Algorithm to simplify a weighted directed graph of debts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts)

The first answer gives some ideas for algorithms.
But the second answer has the link to the academic paper which goes into depth about this problem.