# Reducing the number of edges in a graph (example: refund between people)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Let's take an example to explain my problem. 4 persons (A, B, C and D) must refund some money to each other:

- A must refund 10€ to B
- B must refund 5€ to C
- B must refund 5€ to D
- C must refund 5€ to D

This can be clearly set as a weighted and directed graph. But instead of all these refund, this problem can be simplified "equivalently" as:

- A must refund 10€ to D

For a general graph and apart from the brut force algorithm which might cost a lot for a big graph, is there an algorithm that computes this "reduced" graph (ie: with a less number of edges)? How about with cycle?

I'm not sure this kind of problem enters the "shortest path" problem or minimum spawning graph...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts

Comment: As you'll see if you follow @user152468's link, the problem of minimising edges is at least as hard as the NP-hard Subset Sum problem.  OTOH, you can get a pretty low edge count with some simple heuristics.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks to the two of you!