# Algorithm to complete many transactions within members of a group in least no. of steps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

suppose we have a situation as follows:

```
A has to give $10 to B. 
B has to give $20 to C. 
C has to give $10 to D.
```

Now this situation can be simplified as follows:

```
A loses $10 i.e A=-10
B gains $10 from B but loses $20 to C i.e B=-10
C gains $20 from B but loses $10 to D i.e c=10
D gains $10 i.e D=10
```

so, the transaction can be simplified as:
**A gives $10 to C and B gives $10 to D.**

another example:

```
A gives $1 to B.
B gives $1 to C.
C gives $1 to D.
```

this can be simplified as:
**A gives $1 to D.**

In a similar manner to the above examples, I wanted to make a computer program to find simplest way to complete any given set of transactions. But I can't device algorithm for this. If anyone has idea for this please help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want an algorithm for this problem change the [tag:c] tag to [tag:language-agnostic].

Comment: And if you want a solution in C then you first have to tell us what you have done, what you have tried, and what problems you have with your code. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can model this as a directed graph, compute the net out-flow from each node, for all nodes with +ve outflow, collect their money and then distribute to the remaining.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: It's actually NP-hard to find a minimum number of transactions -- see my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts/15742800#comment22375319_15742800.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts.  Briefly: There are good heuristics, but actually finding the *minimum* number of transactions is an NP-hard problem (see my preceding comment).

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest the following algo :

1. Assign an array for each user and an array for their transaction. Example: `user = [A,B,C,D]; sum = [0,0,0,0];`
2. Update the sum array with each transaction Example :`[-10,10,0,0] -> [-10,-10,20,0] -> [-10,-10,10,10]`
3. Sort the array using any algorithm of complexity O(nlogn). Also update the user array simultaneously.
4. Find the negative and positive junction in the sum array(Ideally you can store it during the sorting or you can do binary search).
5. Next, distribute the negative values from the sum array into the positive values. Example : In our case the sum array after sort will be same as original `[-10,-10,10,10]` and the positive-negative junction is the 2nd index of the sum array. So we start distributing in a loop as `sum[i] into sum[2 + i]` and find the excess or deficit in sum and adjust it in the next iteration.