# Minimize transaction costs for settling debts in a pool

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Suppose a group of friends shared some expenses across a month, and need to settle debts at the end. Each friend has a certain amount of money they should give/receive (the sum of debts and receivable amounts is zero), but everything must be settled with direct transfers (no central pool, only money from one person to another), and each transfer has a cost.

For example, suppose 3 people, A, B and C.

- Person A must pay $100
- Person B must receive $50
- Person C must receive $50

The cost of each transaction can be described by the following matrix(the person in the row paying to the person in the column).

[image]

Given these costs, the optimal solution would be

- Person A transfers $100 to Person B
- Person B transfers $50 to Person C

This settles all debts with a transaction cost of 2. How can I generalize this?

All I could find searching was for simplifying chain debts (person A owes person B that owes person C, so person A owes person C).

The closest I found is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimize-cash-flow-among-given-set-friends-borrowed-money/), but it doesn't have costs for transactions.

**Backstory**(if anyone is interested):

We live in a house with 8 people, and each month we pay bills from our own money and annotate it in a spreadsheet so at the end of the month we share the expenses fairly. However we have accounts on different banks, and some of these require fees for transferring money to other banks, so we prefer to keep transactions from the same bank.

Comment: While this is an interesting algorithmic problem, it seems like the underlying financial problem would be better solved by a financial solution. I'm not a finance expert, but you could try asking on the [personal finance site](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do transfers have a fixed price or % of the transferred amount?

Comment: fixed price is what we need, and I suppose it's simpler. If there are resources for % of transfer, I'm sure I could find a use to it too, or at least draw inspiration.

Comment: A starting point is the [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). For each pair, the shortest path tells you the cheapest way to transfer money between those two. For example, the shortest path from A to C is ABC. With 8 people there are 28 shortest paths to find.

Comment: Even the unweighted version of this problem (in which we simply want to minimise the *number* of transactions) is actually NP-hard -- it amounts to the Subset Sum problem in disguise.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15723165/47984 for more.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm having trouble understanding how this ammounts to the subset sum problem, since transfers don't have to be exactly what a person needs. But I will keep looking into it. But anyway, I took your word for it and gave up on a good solution. I've took user3386109 advice on using minpaths and I am coding a branch-and-bound algorithm. Until now it's performance is absolutely ridiculous(some seconds for 8 people in python, minutes for 9). I will soon post an answer with this algorithm in case someone finds useful.

Comment: When every transaction costs $1, the goal is to use the *fewest* transactions.  Usually, if there are k people involved, this requires k-1 transactions -- but if there is a proper subset of m people, m < k, whose total amounts owed and owing sum to zero, then this subset can be treated as an independent subproblem and solved separately using m-1 transactions, and the remaining k-m people must also have total amounts owed and owing summing to 0, so that subproblem can be solved for k-m-1, for a total of k-2 overall.  Recursing further could save even more transactions.

Comment: To solve an instance of Subset Sum using an algorithm for solving your problem, make a person for each of the n numbers in the input to the SS instance, and one more person with whatever balance is necessary to make the sum of all amounts zero.  Now pass this as input to your algorithm, with the cost of each transaction set to $1.  If your algorithm reports a minimum cost of n, then no subset of the original n numbers sum to 0; if it reports a lower cost, then at least one such subset exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @j_random_hacker explained this problem is np-hard in the comments, I lost all hope of making a pretty solution and set out to do one that works.

Following @user3386109's suggestion, also in the comments, I based myself on minpaths to solve the problem. So I began by using the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm] to find the minimum cost to get money from a person to another for every pair. This yields a matrix of the minimum cost for transferring money from the person in the row to the person in the column. I also applied the modification(it is available in the Wikipedia article in the Path Reconstruction section) to obtain a matrix that yields the next node(next hop, the actual person you must send your money if want to reach the person in the column with minimal cost) for the person in the row to transfer money to the person in the column.

Example of the initialized matrixes, and the result after running the algorithm(The important elements that changed have a red dot):
[image: Example of matrixes before and after running the Floyd-Warshall algorithm]

I then decided to make simple Branch-and-Bound recursion. Every recursion call would receive a list of debts, a matrix for all transactions so far and the cost to reach this state. It must return TODO. We keep a global for the best solution found, and at the beginning of the recursion call check if the cost to reach this state is already worst than the global best, if it is, we return an "infinite" cost to signal this is not a solution we need to consider.

Then we select someone that owes money in the debt list and for each person that must receive money, we create copies of the debt list and transaction matrix, and simulate the transaction of the maximum amount of money between these two people(If A must pay 100 but C only needs to receive 50, the maximum is 50). The transactions matrix is modified by increasing all transaction in the minpath for these two people by the amount transferred. The cost is incremented if we increased an element that was previously zero. We then call the recursion. If the debt list reaches 0, a solution was found, the global minimum cost is updated and the cost returned is 0.

In a previous version, I spawned a recursion for each pair of owing/receiving person. This yielded horrible performance, and proved unnecessary, since the order of transactions doesn't matter, and any debts that weren't yet settled we be treated at lower levels of recursion.

**This algorithm seemed correct, but there was still a problem!**

In the following example:
[image: matrix of transaction weights for a failed example]

- Person A must pay 40$
- Person B must pay 40$
- Person C must pay 20$
- Person D must receive 100$

The algorithm as it is now, makes A, B, C each make a transfer to D. The actual best way would be to choose one of A, B or C to transfer all the money to D in only one payment.

In this example, person A,B and C all have the same extremely high cost to transfer to D, and the next hop for all of them to get money to D is to go directly to D. However, the optimal solution would be to make everyone transfer all their money to a single person n transfer it to D all in one go. The algorithm is failing to recognize that since someone already made a transfer to person D, the cost of this transaction is 0, and so we should use this new path. To address this issue, I included a matrix for costs and a matrix for paths in the recursion, at the beginning of the recursion we set all costs of transfers that have already been made in this recursion branch to 0, and run Floyd-Warshall algorithm again. The recursion uses these matrixes instead of the global ones and passes them on. Sure, it means multiplying complexity by V^3, but it's the only way I found to solve this issue.

The algorithm seems to be working now, but I will probably keep trying to improve it, especially in code readability. The complete code is available at:
[My gitlab project, inside the calculations folder](https://gitlab.com/ArthurMLago/rateiobot/tree/master/calculadora)

Sorry for the long answer and delay in posting it, but I found important to document my work thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I found another, simpler solution. We're still talking about transfer costs which are proportional to the transferred amount. You can build a simple graph with just as many nodes as people and run the network simplex algorithm. Python example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('A', demand=-100) # A has to send 100
G.add_node('B', demand=50) # B will receive 50
G.add_node('C', demand=50) # C will receive 50

G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=1)
G.add_edge('A', 'C', weight=5)
G.add_edge('B', 'A', weight=1)
G.add_edge('B', 'C', weight=1)
G.add_edge('C', 'A', weight=2)
G.add_edge('C', 'B', weight=2)

print nx.network_simplex(G)
```

outputs `(150, {'A': {'C': 0, 'B': 100}, 'C': {'A': 0, 'B': 0}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 50}})`

Comment: A colleague of mine mentioned the simplex algorithm. He also mentioned that some solvers allowed defining cost functions that have cost 0 if a graph edge is 0, or n(constant) otherwise. When I studied optimization algorithms such as simplex, there was a brief mention of this, and I think the solver would use branch and bound for solving. Do you know if this `networkx` can do this? or any solver that can? For now I am already developing a simple(and very inefficient) branch-and-bound so, I think I will finish that first, and then try find such a solver.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the bank charges a percentage of the transferred amount, your task is finding a [min-cost max flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).

Your graph should have 5 layers.

```
(direction)
    |    Source layer:               S
    |                            /   |    \
    |    Exchange:           A  ---  B  ---  C  (complete graph)
    |                            \   |    / 
    V    Sink           :            T
```

The source is connected to the nodes A, B, C ... The capacity of S -> A is how much A has to pay, and 0 if A does not own money. The cost of the edge is 0.

In the exchange layer A, B, C... are all connected to each other (complete graph).

The capacity of A -> B is infinite and the cost is how much you have to pay after transferring $1 from A to B (same for all pairs).

The nodes are connected to the sink. The capacity of A -> Sink is how much A will receive, and 0 if A does not receive money. The cost of the edge is 0.

Run a min-cost max flow algorithm on the above graph from the root source to the root sink, such as Edmonds-Karp + cycle-canceling. You are probably better off finding a library (such as the Boost Graph Library for C++), instead of implementing the algorithms yourself.

Comment: Your proposed graph structure doesn't seem to support all flows possible in the actual problem - for example, it is not possible to pass money through two intermediates, such as Alice -> Bob -> Charlie -> Dave. While you can use an all-pairs shortest-path algorithm to replace inefficient edges in the original graph with the cost of the cheapest replacement path, I don't know if even that is enough to render the solution optimal.

Comment: It seems like it'd be better to replace the source/mixer/sink layer structure with a complete directed graph.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Right, we need as many mixer layers as many people we have and every subsequent pair of layers should be fully connected (so in the end the mixer layers will contain N^2 nodes where N is the number of people). This adds a lot to the complexity, though. I will think about how we can optimize this.

Comment: I think the unweighted version is a different problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Note that weight of 1 is different from constant 1. Transferring $100 costs $100 vs $1.

Comment: That's true, and that's why I wrote as the first sentence of this response, that this solves a different but similar problem.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that.  I'll delete my earlier comments.