# Matching a group of seller and a group of buyers together

Tags: python, algorithm, economics

I have a list of sellers and a list of buyers. Each contain tupples with the first element being an index (to identify the user) and the other being the amount of goods the person is willing to sell/buy. What is a good and efficient algorithm to optimize the amount of goods that is sold. Users can sell and buy to multiple people at the same time.

I have done a simple algorithm which runs while their are elements in at least one of them. The lists are ordered by amount of goods and the users matched one by one.

Here is my algorithm:

```
      while producers and consumers:
            
            consumer = consumers[0]
            producer = producers[0]
            amount = min(consumer['consuming'], producer['producing'])     
            transfer(consumer,producer,amount)
            consumer['consuming'] -= amount
            producer['producing'] -= amount
            if not producer['producing']:
                del producers[0]
            if not consumer['consuming']:
                del consumers[0]
            else:
                consumers.append(consumer)
                del consumers[0]
```

My goal is to maximize the amount that is transfered while minimizing the time it takes for the algorithm to run.

Comment: Do the users care what price they sell their goods at, or are they willing to sell at any price? E.g. I might be willing to sell my car at $10,000, but not for $9,000, even if there are many more sellers than buyers.

Comment: @NickODell the users do not care what price they sell theirs goods at they only care about the amount of goods they want to sell. However, they don't need to sell all of them.

Comment: Could you show an example of your seller/buyer tuples? Are they literally just `(id, q)` where q is an integer for the amount of goods, or are there multiple "kinds" of goods in this scenario?

Comment: Their is only one kind of good so an example of a tuple would be ("1", 18).

Comment: You already have a way of matching them where all goods that can be sold, should be.  What are you trying to optimize?  Is there any criteria that makes one matching better than another?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723165/algorithm-to-simplify-a-weighted-directed-graph-of-debts

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thanks a lot I will have a look at the different answers !

Comment: @btilly I have added my algorithm. One matching is considered better than an other one if the amount transfered is bigger. My goal is also to minimize the amount of time it takes to find this matching.

Comment: @HugoHazard You'll continue pairing until everything is transferred. The only way I can see that easily speeds up the code is to get rid of your `else` code.  Beyond that you've got micro-optimizations like being sure that you're using the fastest available list operations.  (Often code like `consumers.pop()` will take the last element and will be faster than deleting the first element. Check your language implementation for details.)

Comment: @btilly thank you for your advice I will make sure I do ! Would you have any other recomendations in terms of famous algorithms that could work in this case (other than stable mariage)?

Comment: Nope.  Not everything needs a name.  I think most people would just solve this then move on.